# Adjust Site Display To Device Scale (100%,125%.. or S/M/L ..)

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, cordova

I have an angular site, which is also wrapped as an in-app browser by Cordova.
Although the site looks good on desktop, Ipad and most to mobile devices, when the user
changes his display scale (for example S to L in android or even 100% to 150% in desktop) things are getting broken.

We already found a solution for the text zoom that the user selects, but this one seems more complicated. After some investigation, I found out that there is a lot of chaos. Most people suggested using the window.devicepixelratio, but unfortunately, it seems that although it doest gives to the correct scale using chrome on desktop, it doesn't work on many other devices and browsers.

I am wondering how I can do the following:

1. Detect the zoom/scale of the user display.
2. Easily invert the changes in order to prevent the size from increasing. in the font zoom we use something like this:

```
      private setRootElementFontSize(textZoom: number) {
        this.htmlRootElement = this.element.nativeElement.getRootNode().querySelector('html');
        this.htmlRootElement.style.setProperty('font-size', (this.staticFontSize / textZoom * 100) + 'px', 'important');
      }
```